# How to view Kafka Consumer function response time in New Relic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, newrelic

There is a Kafka Consumer topic for which i want to get response time of the consumer function in new relic. New Relic doesn't seem to capture kafka consumers in transactions.

Is there any way i can get response time of the function everytime the message is consumed by the function in New Relic?

Answer (score 0):

Call a third party function from a different service using @Trace annotation which mirrors the logic used in the consumer